# Selecting multiple date ranges using Select By Attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, date

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. I'm interested in selecting multiple date ranges using Select By Attribute.

I've verified that each date range works. For example Date >= '2015-04-15' AND Date <= '2016-04-15' works great.

But I would like to also select that same date range for 2016-2017. I get an error if I continue with AND for the next range.

Comment: Dates are a special case, different feature storage types (shapefile, personal geodatabase, file geodatabase etc) have their own implementation of date types, can you post a screen shot of your select by attributes dialog and indicate what feature storage type you are selecting from please.

Comment: I'm using a file geodatabase. I do not have access to Arc at the moment, so I can't provide a screenshot.

Comment: Have a read of http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB and https://community.esri.com/thread/105862 from the sounds of it you want to select (datefield >=  '2015-04-15' AND Date <= '2016-04-15' ) **OR**  (datefield >=  '2015-04-15' AND Date <= '2016-04-15' ) - change the values to suit; your error is probably *selection returns no records* because you're excluding with an AND statement.

Comment: I just gave that a try but it returned a selection of random values. Any thoughts? Here's what I used - ( Date >= date '2015-04-16 00:00:00' AND Date <= date '2016-04-15 00:00:00' ) OR ( Date >= date '2017-04-16 00:00:00' AND Date <= date '2018-04-15 00:00:00' ) OR ( Date <= date '2018-04-16 00:00:00' AND Date <= date '2019-04-15 00:00:00' )

Answer (score 1):

Michael's earlier comment did indeed work - (datefield >= '2015-04-15' AND Date <= '2016-04-15' ) OR (datefield >= '2015-04-15' AND Date <= '2016-04-15' ).  I just had to restart ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword BETWEEN to check for date range like this

```
DATE BETWEEN date '2019-04-08 00:00:00' and date '2019-04-17 00:00:00' OR DATE BETWEEN date '2018-04-08 00:00:00' and date '2018-04-17 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I don't have that syntax within the options for Select By Attributes. Even when I type it in, it gives me an error.

Comment: Did you try and copy and paste into select by attribute and change field name? I copy and paste into my dataset just now and it worked ok.

Comment: It worked after I restarted ArcMap. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, anytime.